# Sql query not working on matlab properly

Tags: sql, matlab, qsqlquery

So i'm working on a laravel project where i  pass some data to matlab and then matlab will edit them..everything works fine except the function of matlab that i wrote..

```
function show(a)
econ=database('datamining','root','');
curs=exec(con,'SELECT name FROM dataset_choices WHERE id = a');
curs = fetch(curs);
curs.Data
end
```

i want this function to display the name of the dataset the user choose..the problem is that it doesnt work writing just where id = a... but if i write for example where id=1 it works..
i tried to display just the **a** with **disp(a)** to see what is the value of the **a** and it is store the right id that user had choose..so how can i use it in my query??

Comment: Is your 'a' variable a string or double?

Comment: @Flynn integer..it is store the id of a table

Comment: You need to use [`sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) to build your query string. Just be advised that this can potentially create a giant security hole.

Comment: Let me know if answer below works now. You need to make sure 'a' is a string if you're using it inside a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
a = num2str(a); % or make sure the user inputs a string instead
curs=exec(con,['SELECT name FROM dataset_choices WHERE id = ',a]);
```

If a = '1', then the brackets would print:
'SELECT name FROM dataset_choices WHERE id = 1'

Comment: Great! Glad I could help